# cudaError/CUresult incompatibility when upgrading to CUDA 11

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda

I am trying to upgrade a project from VS2013/CUDA 8.0 to VS2019/CUDA11.1.

Everything works fine in VS2013/CUDA8, but when I try to build the project with VS2019/CUDA11, I am getting this compatibility error about the cuda_helper:

```
1>C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v11.1\common\inc\helper_cuda.h(571): error : argument of type "CUresult" is incompatible with parameter of type "cudaError_t"
1>          detected during instantiation of "void check(T, const char *, const char *, int) [with T=CUresult]"
1>C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v11.1\common\inc\helper_cuda_drvapi.h(123): here
```

What changed in CUDA 11 that can leads to this error ?
How can I locate and correct the error in my project ?

Comment: None of that is part of the CUDA toolkit, it is part of the CUDA samples and totally undocumented and definitely not intended for use in other code. It looks like a conflict between CUDA runtime and driver API error handling functions, but you are completely on your own on how to fix it

Comment: somewhere in your code you're using some function to check a driver API return status, when that function, supported by `cuda_helper`, is intended to check a runtime API return status.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue importing `<helper_cuda.h>` rather than `<helper_cuda_drvapi.h>`

Indeed, CUDA Driver return a CUresult whereas the CUDA Runtime returns a cudaError_t.
It may have change from one CUDA version to another.

Otherwise, as mentioned by talonmies, this may not be a good idea to include some of the CUDA samples in my project.